# How to get route parameter in aurelia custom component

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm creating a custom component in aureliajs framework and injecting it a `Router` instance:

```
@inject(Router)
export class Pagination {
    constructor(router) {
        this.router = router;
    }
}
```

It will be used with list view-models in order to setup some basic pagination. Therefore I need to read current page number from an active route (that would look like: `orders/:pageNum`. I'm not sure however how to do it? I mean - I know it should probably be placed in `Pagination` attached method, but how to get to this `:pageNum` param?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a bindable property in your custom element. Take the page number from the active route and bind it to the custom element. For instance:

```
import { bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Router)
export class Pagination {

    @bindable page;

    constructor(router) {
        this.router = router;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<pagination page.bind="page"></pagination>
```

To get the page number in the active route, use the `activate()` hook:

```
activate(params) {
   this.page = params.pageNum;
}
```

Comment: I'd rather do it the way that only my custom element knows which page number is the active page, so without binding it.

Comment: Well, you could do it, but your component would have 2 responsibilities. If you change the way you handle active pages, you would have to change the screen component and the page component. If you bind the page number to the page component, no matter how you are handling active pages, the component will always have the correct value

Answer (score 1):

You can use `router.currentInstruction.params` and `router.currentInstruction.queryParams`.

You can also observe the router to be notified when the route changes:

```
let sub = this.bindingEngine.propertyObserver(
    this.router, 'currentInstruction').subscribe(currentInstruction => {

  console.log(currentInstruction);

});
```

Comment: router.currentInstruction is always null in my case